# angular filter for the ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My json object is having a field called keynote with value 0 or 1

```
[{
    "id": 111,
    "title": "Senior Vice President and Chief Analytics Officer",
    "name": "jon doe",
    "company": "Entertainment Corporation",
    "keynote": 1
},
{
    "id": 102,
    "title": "CEO and Mobile Market Strategist",
    "name": "john",
    "company": "Research",
    "keynote": 1
},
{
    "id": 102,
    "title": "CEO and Mobile Market Strategist",
    "name": "john",
    "company": "Research",
    "keynote": 0
},
{
    "id": 102,
    "title": "CEO and Mobile Market Strategist",
    "name": "john",
    "company": "Research",
    "keynote": 0
}]
```

I want to display two kinds of lists in my app. one list with keynote speakers and the other list with keynote = 0.

```
<li class="table-view-cell" data-ng-repeat="speaker in speakers | filter:speaker.keynote=1 ">
<span class="speaker-name">{{speaker.name}}</span>
</li>

<li class="table-view-cell" data-ng-repeat="speaker in speakers | filter:speaker.keynote=0 ">
<span class="speaker-name">{{speaker.name}}</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is `filter:{propertyName:'value'}`, so `ng-repeat="speaker in speakers | filter:{keynote:0}"` will work for you.

I recommend implementing something like this to make your code more DRY:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="i in range"> // or i in [0,1]
    <h3>Keynote: {{i}}</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="speaker in speakers | filter:{keynote:i}">
        <span>{{speaker.name}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

An example of auto generating `range` using Lodash:

```
  $scope.range = _.sortBy(_.uniq($scope.speakers, 'keynote').map(function(item) {
    return item.keynote;
  }), function(a, b) {
    return a < b;
  });
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsbin.com/tovati/2/edit)

Responding to your comments, here's a way to make your particular code DRY:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(title, isKeynote) in {Keynote:1, Sessions:0}">
    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="speaker in speakers | filter:{keynote:isKeynote}">
        <span>{{speaker.name}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsbin.com/tovati/3/edit)

Comment: actually don't wanna combine, both are separate lists with different header contents

Comment: @user2727195 that's fine, but did I not answer your question? I was just adding additional details...

Comment: no, because in your h3 where it says Keynote, I have a different title for each list, it's repeat but that's how it is, unless you can show if I can have a different title for each iteration, I've only two at the moment, 1->key note speaker, 0->session speaker

Comment: @user2727195 my `h3` doesn't matter, does it? The problem with your code is that the `filter` expression isn't correct. Just look at the first line of my answer and nothing else, if that makes you happier...

Comment: ok, got that, in case I wanna follow DRY, how could I have implemented while displaying a different title/text from pre-defined values (keynote or session) in `h3` for each, right now I've duplicate code, one for keynote and one for session